# Flutter: Closure dynamic from Function static

Tags: flutter

I have created a function to get a random element from a list. It works perfectly in dartpad but when I put it into my Flutter app I get the following error:

```
Closure: (List<dynamic>) => dynamic from Function 'player1': static.
```

The contents of the dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

List<String> players = ["Alice", "Jane", "Susan"];
String tempPlayer = "";

player1(List players) {
  //players[Random().nextInt(players.length)];
  String tempPlayer = players[Random().nextInt(players.length)];
  return tempPlayer;
}

class RandPlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandPlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RandPlay> createState() => _RandPlayState();
}

class _RandPlayState extends State<RandPlay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(player1);
                });
              },
              child: Text("Random")),
          Text("$player1"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to this and I am really confused... I have tried searching for similar situations to no avail. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`player1` is a method, expect a list.

You can do it like

```dart
List<String> players = ["Alice", "Jane", "Susan"];

String player1(players) {
  String tempPlayer = players[Random().nextInt(players.length)];
  return tempPlayer;
}

class RandPlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandPlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RandPlay> createState() => _RandPlayState();
}

class _RandPlayState extends State<RandPlay> {
  late String tempPlayer = player1(players);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                tempPlayer = player1(players);
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("Random")),
          Text("$tempPlayer"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want it to be a function and not a method enclosed in a class as it has to be called from multiple places.

Comment: How about your `tempPlayer`, does it have to be on multiple place ? try update answer

Comment: This doesn't help. I have removed tempPlayer completely, new code is: ` player1(List players) {
  return players[Random().nextInt(players.length)];
} `'

Comment: did you test the full snippet I've included ?